# Running JUnit test for child class without test method override

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

If I have an arbitrary class that defines a JUnit test method, and a child class that overrides test behavior but not the actual test method itself, is it possible to run the ChildClass test directly in IntelliJ?

```
class ParentClass
{
    @Test
    public void testSomeBehavior()
    {
        doTest();
    }

    protected void doTest()
    {
        // ParentClass specific behavior
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass
{
    @Override
    protected void doTest()
    {
        // ChildClass specific behavior
    }
}
```

My current work around is to kick off a run at the class level (ChildClass), kill the run, and then manually select my test from the Run/Debug screen. But this is not ideal.

I do know if my parent class was defined as abstract then IntelliJ will give me a list of possible implementing classes that can run the given test. But I do not see that option when parent class is instantiable.

Comment: I HIGHLY recommend not extending a test class in this way.  If you want to reuse code, create a library or something.  Some redundant code in tests is not a shame (and I'm about the strongest DRY advocate you are likely to encounter).  If you need two identical sets of test with slightly different behavior to test a parent and child, parameterize the tests slightly. For what you seem to be doing, nothing you can try will be worse than inheritance in the long run.

Comment: This is for work so I don't really have the option of refactoring. I'm not asking for new test development but more for QOL while debugging & interacting with legacy tests.

Comment: It will never be easy to run.  For the minimum work you might try copying the tests it into 2 separate tests and then just modifying them slightly to deal with the different classes you are testing, it'll be easier.  If you really can't--good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why could you want to do it...
It is not recommended. But if you are interesting to create nested tests using JUNIT5 maybe you can use this documentation.

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-nested

Comment: The question is not about _writing_ nested tests but specifically for _running_ nested tests that have already been developed.